# Ignore unresolved references in IntelliJ

Tags: go, intellij-idea, bazel

How can I ignore an unresolved reference in IntelliJ in Go? I have generated a Go file using an external build system that defines `workspaceGeneratedDir` that's not checked into source code.

[image: bazel generated dir]

Comment: maybe using build tags ?

Comment: You can't ignore unresolved references in Go, generally, regardless of your IDE/editor. If the definition is defined by generated code, then the generated code needs to be present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is create a file with a build-tag (as mentioned in the comments). For example:

```golang
// +build develop

package workspace

var workspaceGeneratedDir string
```

Then add the `develop` build tag to the Goland IDE in the Custom Tags field:

[image]

When running tests or executing your application locally add
`-tags=develop` to the command. If you don't like that you can do it the other way around:

```golang
// +build !production

...
```

Now you only need to add the tag to your command in your production build pipeline to ignore this file in production builds: `go build -tags=production .`